# mootools "fx.styles" and "addevent" equivalent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

having a lot of trouble finding the equivalent of this code in jquery

```
var reveal = new Fx.Styles(div, {
    duration: 200,
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeIn,
    wait: true,
    fps: 24
});

reveal.addEvent('onStart', function(){
    tt_has(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would become:

```
$(div).animate( {left: 500, top: 500}, 200, 'linear');
tt_has(true);
```

There is no 'start' event in jquery animations (they start automatically), so we call `tt_has(true)` right after the call to `.animate()`,

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: there is a huge difference here. the mootools code above sets up an fx.styles instance and adds a start event but does not start animating. you do that later by doing `reveal.start()` which will fire the `onStart` event - and it will keep on doing that on any request for the instance.start method subsequently for that element. the jquery code you did will start animating it automatically and the onStart code will run immediately - which is not reusable and cannot be deferred to later.

Comment: why did you put in {left: 500, top: 500} ?

Comment: because jQuery.animate needs to start the animation. this is equivalent to `reveal.start({left:500, top: 500});`